# ChartJs hide label and it's values

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I'm working on a chart using Chart.js, the chart have a column for each month, like so:
[image: Chart Example]
What I need to do now is create a filter, so when you select it, only the last 3 or 6 months would appear.
However, I don't want to lose my data (that's why I don't want to just splice my data).
What I'm after is something like hide(), but only on specified Labels/Data.

I tried to find something like this in the documentation, but wasn't able to.

If someone could help me with this, would be great.
Thanks!

**Edit**
I've decided to just create a 'global' variable with all my data, and every time I need to update de chart to show only 'x' columns, I just loop through this variable 'x' times to feed the chart.